# Can't export map from TileWMS

Tags: canvas, export, openlayers-3

I have problem with exporting map from `TileWMS ol.source.TileWMS` or `ol.source.XYZ`. I was trying do by this:

```
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/export-map.html?q=export
```

but it just wrote:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
>   'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

I found that problem is in `ol.source.TileWMS, ol.source.XYZ`. I tried html2canvas, blob, canvas-to-blob but nothing can't export map.

Can somebody help me how to export map from ol.source.TileWMS, ol.source.XYZ?

Comment: Sorry but there is no work around for the cross domain error. This is to protect people from malicious content that could be stored in the image. If you are doing this for your self you can turn off security via the browser's command line options. For chrome this is  `--disable-web-security` this can only be done on the client side by the user.

Comment: Or how it could be at least print?